# Redirect Command to Email

Tags: boot, networking, pxe, ifconfig, redirect

I have a PXE server and need to do a redirect command at the end of the script.

```
ifconfig | grep inet >> ip.txt
```

send to My_EMAIL

Am I on the right path?

Edit include from answer posted as an edit to this question:

Ok so the problem is that we have double work. The dhcp server is setup and I can't add pxe to it so I need a file with the IP address and MAC address to add it to the dhcp server. I would like that sent to my email. I have 40 machines to image and don't want to connect a KVM to each machine

think MaaS might store that information locally on my PXE machine

Thanks

---

Ok so the problem is that we have double work. The dhcp server is setup and I can't add pxe to it so I need a file with the IP address and MAC address to add it to the dhcp server. I would like that sent to my email. I have 40 machines to image and don't want to connect a KVM to each machine

think MaaS might store that information locally on my PXE machine

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I understand you PXE boot a client, and then you want to get its IP and email it to yourself?

Comment: As far as I know sending email is not gonna be something easily done without a whole lot of knowledge about how email actually works. I've tried it several times, each time ending with utter failure. It's rather easy to install mail servers. It's a giant pain in the dick to get them to actually send mail off the box. I've actually had easier times sending information via JSON to a cgi Python script on a webserver on the LAN and then dealing with it there.

Comment: Basically, if all you need is the information collected in one place, emailing it is *not* the easiest way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to parse your question. I'm expanding my comment into an answer.

From your stated requirements, email is not what you need. You need to transfer text information from 40 instances to one box, collate it, and then feed that information to your DHCP server.

In broad strokes, I would set up a machine accessible to the instances with a basic web stack on it, LAMP or even just nginx and a cgi or whatever. Your script then should POST to http://192.168.X.X/scriptName.py. That Python script (or JavaScript if you know that) can then process the incoming text data (IP and whatnot) into a file that yet another script can periodically read and send DHCP lease requests (or whatever) to the DHCP server.

It's probably an hour or two of work to set all that up on a Linux box, but if this is a one time set up, it's likely not worth the effort. Just go get the information and send the requests.  If it's more of a "this is how we set up customer instances on a customer site" then you'll likely need to build something like this.